# For loop with string variables

Tags: r, for-loop

I am doing multiple t tests in R, like these:

```
t.test(subset(data, type=="1" & string1=="string123" & string2=="string456")$value,
               subset(data, type=="3" & string1=="string123" & string2=="string456")$value
```

I wish to perform these tests for multiple values of string2:

```
list <- c("string456", "string457")
for (i in list){ t.test(paste(subset(data, type=="1" & string1=="string123" & string2=="",i,"")$value,
                  subset(data, type=="3" & string1=="string123" & string2=="",i,"")$value)
```

This produces an error:

> Error: unexpected numeric constant in "for (i in list){t.test(paste("subset(data, type=="1"

Any suggestions?

Comment: didn't understand this :`string2=="",i,""` ; replace it with `string2 == i`

Comment: `for (i in c("a", "bb", "ccc")) print(paste0("xxx.", i))` i.e. the for-loop isn't the problem

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `paste()` inside your loop:

```
list <- c("string456", "string457")
for (i in list) { 
  t.test(subset(data, type=="1" & string1=="string123" & string2==i)$value,subset(data, type=="3" & string1=="string123" & string2==i)$value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lapply` instead of a `for`-loop and save your t-test results in a list for later use.

```
list <- c("string456", "string457")
t_test_results <- lapply(list, function(x)
                         t.test(subset(data, type == "1" & string1 == "string123" & string2 == x)$value, 
                                subset (data, type == "3" & string1 == "string123" & string2 == x)$value))
```

This way, you could even omit the `$value` to store the whole test data in the list, and later call the value with `t_test_results[[1]]$value`.